# Angular asynchronous request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I'm new in programming and learning to do the angular example project from the book of Adam Freeman.
The problem is in asynchronous HTTP request to the server.

Here is a part of my Model with saveProduct() method:

```
export class Model {
private products: Product[];
private locator = (p: Product, id: number) => p.id == id;
    constructor(private dataSource: RestDataSource) {
        this.dataSource.getData().subscribe(data => this.products = data);
    }
    getProducts(): Product[] {
        return this.products;
    }
    getProduct(id: number): Product {
        return this.products.find(p => this.locator(p, id));
    }
    saveProduct(product: Product) {
        if (product.id == 0 || product.id == null) {
            this.dataSource.saveProduct(product).subscribe(p => this.products.push(p));
        } else {
            this.dataSource.updateProduct(product).subscribe(p => {
            let index = this.products.findIndex(item => this.locator(item, p.id));
            this.products.splice(index, 1, p);
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is my RestDataSource:

```
export const REST_URL = new OpaqueToken("rest_url");
@Injectable()
export class RestDataSource {
constructor(private http: Http, @Inject(REST_URL) private url: string) { }

getData(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Get, this.url);
}
saveProduct(product:Product): Observable<Product>{
    return this.sendRequest(RequestMethod.Post, this.url, product);    
}



private sendRequest(verb: RequestMethod, url: string, body?: Product) {
    return this.http.request(new Request({
    method: verb,
    url: url,
    body: body, 
    headers: new Headers({
        "Access-Key": "<secret>",
        "Application-Name": "exampleApp"})
        })).map(response => response.json()).catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(`Network Error: ${error.statusText} (${error.status})`));
    }
}
```

I assumed that in response after saveProduct request must be a Product object, that we can push in our Array of Products, but I always get in response  this:

{fieldCount: 0, affectedRows: 1, insertId: 120, serverStatus: 2, warningCount: 0, …}  and empty row in the table

Please, help me understand the problem. What is wrong here?

Comment: it looks like you are getting some sort of status object back from the saveProduct call, rather than a Product object.

Comment: Yes!  I also think so, but in the book is the same code. I don't understand how it works.